Scoped Roles in EF Core
I can't find anything useful about this online, but I'm trying to come up with something like a scoped role using EF Core with identity.
The gist is this: there are users and there are districts and there are roles. A user might have a reporter role in District xyz, no role in District abc, and then a different role in District def.
So I'm trying to create something like a DistrictUserRole - where the role claims are scoped to that entity.
The class would look like this:
public class DistrictUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>()
{
    public virtual required ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual required District District { get; set; }
    public virtual required IdentityRole<Guid> User { get; set; }
}

So this class would have a 3 way primary keys I guess.
Or I could remove the user and create DistrictRole which would inherit from IdentityRole, and a user could have multiple DistrictRoles. I'm not sure the scope would work for that though, and I'm not sure if it doesn't just amount to the same thing.
My question: is this a good idea? Would I be better off just handling this with filters and not bothering with trying to model the abstraction?

What you describe is an extra Claim, not a role, and has little to do with EF Core (beyond storage). EF Core does not implement or enforce security, ASP.NET Identity does. Check Claims-Based Authorization and Policy-based Authorization in the docs. Claims can come from many sources, not just the database.

I don't think you should go with roles. This is not a role thing.  While roles are claims, not all claims are roles. Depending on the identity issuer a role may be a collection of users that may apply claims for group members, as well as an actual claim on an identity. However, claims are meant to be information about an individual user. Using roles to add claims to a user can confuse the boundary between the user and their individual claims. Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core

What you describe as "scoped role" is called Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) and everyone claims they do it. Unfortunately, in many cases they're confused with security groups, which aren't the same thing at all. ASP.NET's Roles are closer to security groups than RBAC. You shouldn't try to model Reporter at Accounting as an IdentityUserRole. You can store that in a separate table though and use it to construct a claim that gets validated by a custom policy

@PanagiotisKanavos - so probably implementing handlers is the way to go and then just have a good way of constructing the claims?

Could one have multiple classes that inherit from IdentityUserClaim, or am I better off just creating generic classes and using them that way?
